# ROSWTF "unexpectedly connected" message and creation of new nodes

Tags: ros, gazebo, roslaunch, rqt-graph, graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting multi-robot simulation (currently involving two robots) and the problem is with the roswtf which throws "WARNING The following nodes are unexpectedly connected:" warning as mentioned in [this terse and beautiful question](http://answers.ros.org/question/9385/roswtf-warnings-unexpectedly-connected/) (But the answer is not satisfactory). But, in my case, roswtf is also creating /tf topics and creating new nodes like /roswtf_11591_1480848778816 and /roswtf_11751_1480848797413 each time I run roswtf.

The rqt_graph s are as shown.

[image] and [image]

Can somebody be requested to let me know why this is happening and the reason behind it? Thanks for your time and consideration.

Reference note: The entire log can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/2pjLhJML).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249450/roswtf-%22unexpectedly-connected%22-message-and-creation-of-new-nodes/) by [PrasadNR](https://answers.ros.org/users/28296/prasadnr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2016-12-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roswtf is initialized as an 'anonymous' node. Which is why it's node name has a unique number attached for each launch so that the node name will not collide with any other instances.

See the anonymous initialization option at http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown

It subscribes to `/tf` and you are not visualizing new topics but new edges in the graph.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PrasadNR](https://answers.ros.org/users/28296/prasadnr/) on 2017-01-26**:
+1 "you are not visualizing new topics but new edges in the graph"